# Custom Expo Development Client for Simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, simulator

I had a specific question about installing a custom expo development client on a simulator, specifically an iOS simulator. I know that there is a way to install an expo build in a simulator (outlined here: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/simulators/), but this is just a build and not a development client, which are two very different things. The concept of an expo development client is outlined here: https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/. That means there is no Fast Refresh available, and I cannot modify my app in real-time by changing my code. This is a really important feature for me because I need to make sure my app is compatible with all iPhone sizes, and I need to be able to see the changes quickly without having to make a build every single time. Does anyone know how to do this, or if this is currently even possible?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Fast refresh works on Expo as well as with vanilla RN.

Comment: @Abe I know that the Fast refresh works on Expo Go with the simulator, but if you have native code and a bare workflow, you need to create an expo development client build for the simulator, and as far as I have seen, the refresh doesn't work on my simulator. Just shows the code that is already built.

Comment: Native code changes will always require a rebuild. This is common to all RN. Fast refresh only applies to Javascript. However, it sounds like your needs are loading the app on several simulators to check UI, and as long as you are building that in JS, you will be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Abe I built my project for the iOS simulator with the command `eas build --profile simulator --platform ios`, then I followed the instructions of downloading the tar.gz file from my expo dashboard, extracting the .app file, and dragging it into the simulator. Once I dragged it into the simulator, I can click on the app and use it, but it doesn't act like a development client should where it responds to changes when I change my JS code. Instead its just a prebuilt app that is not connected to Metro at all. This is unlike my phone, where I can scan the QR Code and see JS changes live.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you were doing a build and exporting.  Live refresh will not work in that case.

Comment: @Abe All good, I don't think I explained it well. So are you saying that there is no official way of doing this? In that case, I'm not really sure how to develop my app and test it for multiple screen sizes if I cannot make live changes on the simulator. This used to work before I migrated to a bare workflow and started using EAS build + Expo Dev Clients, but I had to because of the fact that I am using native code.

Comment: Are you changing native code often? You might be better off using an ejected Expo project or a vanilla RN project. You will still have to rebuild after native code changes, but you'll get fast refresh for Javascript changes.

Comment: @Abe I am not changing the native code often, at least in the case of the simulator. I am just changing the JS code so I can see the UI changes on the simulator. However, I really am not interested in ejecting from Expo because my code heavily utilizes Expo APIs.

Comment: You can still use Expo libraries if you eject. https://docs.expo.dev/expokit/eject/

Comment: @Abe Oh ok interesting, I was not aware of that. Still, I really like using Expo for the ease of building my app and shipping it to the App Store and Google Play Store, so I am not planning on ejecting it. I am going to open a Github issue and make a feature request for the issue I am having.

Comment: Ok. Best of luck!

Comment: You need to use and configure eas-updates if you want to update your development client like you would with Expo Go with Expo Publish. The expo-dev-client serves the same purpose as Expo Go, but is much more customizable. You can send updates to it by scanning a QR code or setting up `eas update` which is in preview right now, and needs a paid license to access use the feature in preview. Without that paid access, you are stuck with updating the dev client via QR code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more detailed explanation of the issue can be found here: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/custom-dev-clients-for-simulator

Essentially the issue that I had was I did not set up my `eas.json` file correctly. I needed to change the `preview` build profile in the `eas.json` file so that it contained these parameters: `"developmentClient": true` and `"ios": { "simulator": true }` I then built my project using the command `eas build --profile preview`. I then followed the steps of downloading the tar.gz file, extracting the .app file, dragging it into the simulator, and I was able to successfully open the app and connect it to Metro where I could then see live changes.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Raamiz Abbasi said, you can set `developmentClient` and `simulator` to true in your `eas.json` however if you want to go further, you can also use `expo-dev-client` to create a "custom expo go app" which is basically a customized expo go which you can publish updates to with the `eas-update`.

Expo Go and this new "development client" are both clients which serve the purpose of displaying your JS bundles. But, with the expo-dev-client you can do cool things like add extra debug buttons into the menu, or run publishes (or eas updates in this case) which would automatically feed into the dev client.

The reasoning for doing this, besides adding extra debug stuff in the debug menu, would be to avoid the pain of only being able to `expo publish` a "release" build. Right now `expo publish` builds used with expo go cannot be debuggable.

Comment: referring to your answer; are "using `expo-dev-client`" and "EAS build on a preview profile with `developmentClient` and `simulator`" **two different** methods? And by "using `expo-dev-client` did you mean something different than running `npx expo start --dev-client`, which in turn would still need a expo-dev-client (built by the explained EAS method) installed on the simulator/device? I'm just trying to understand the two different ways... or aren't those two actions working together as one method?

Comment: And on a related note, what are the difference between these two build profiles in terms of typical use-cases?

*"build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
    },
    "simulator": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    }*